# gmaps4rails change map id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I have a Rails 3.2.x app which I'm using `gmaps4rails 2.0.0.pre` (yes I know it's an old version).  I'm using this to plot different vehicles (units) on a map in a gps view/controller.  Now I'm trying to leverage `gmaps4rails` to display a map in a different view/controller to display a building (facility) location in the facility show view.

On initial page load I display the facility's marker on a map in the proper location.  However after a few moments the marker will disappear entirely.  I know why this is happening but not how to fix it.

I have the following `Coffeescript` which looks for an `ID` of `#map` and calls `/units` and `/gps` paths to update the GPS view/map in quasi-realtime.

**gps.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  if $("#map").length > 0
    setInterval (->
      $.getScript "/units"

  # Get all current locations, find each marker in the map, and update it's position
  $.getJSON "/gps", (data) ->
    $.each(data, (i, val) ->
      marker = $.grep Gmaps.map.markers, (e) ->
        e.id is val.id
      marker[0].setPosition(val.lat, val.lng) if marker[0]?
    )
), 5000

$('.marker-link').on 'click', ->
  id = $(this).data("marker-id")
  marker = $.grep Gmaps.map.markers, (e) ->
    e.id is id

  marker[0].showInfowindow() if marker[0]?
```

So the problem is that the default `ID` for gmaps4rails maps is `#map`.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a new map using the plugin with a different `ID` so that I can display a facility location and not call the coffeescript to refresh.

Here's what my facility model/view/controller look like.  Everything works but the marker disappears due to the coffee script calling `#map`.  I don't want to lose this coffeescript functionality as it updates my gps show view with markers properly.  I'd like to figure out a way to generate a gmaps4rails map and change the `ID`.

**facility.rb**

```
  acts_as_gmappable process_geocoding: false
```

**facilities_controller**

```
def show
    @facility = Facility.find(params[:id])
    @marker = @facility.to_gmaps4rails do |facility, marker|
      #marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "unit_infowindow", locals: {unit: unit})
      marker.json({id: facility.id})
    end
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @marker }
    end
  end
```

**facility show.html.erb**

```
<div class="well">
  <%= gmaps(markers: {data: @marker, options: {rich_marker: true, "auto_zoom" => false}}) %>
</div>
```

Is there a way to generate a gmaps4rails map, and override the default `ID` of `#map` so I can keep the marker from disappearing and continue to use my coffeescript in my GPS view?

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.  I would greatly appreciate it.

And if my question is confusing or needs more explanation, I will be happy to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out how to override the `ID` of `#map` in `gmaps4rails`.

By setting `:map_options` to an `ID` of `facility_map` my coffeesript does not fire on this view and the marker remains static as I wanted.

```
<div class="well">
  <%= gmaps(markers: {data: @marker, options: {rich_marker: true}}, :map_options => {:id => "facility_map"}) %>
</div>
```

If any of you have a better way of doing this, please let me know.  But so far this seems to be working for me.